# Hide form2 from taskbar

Tags: forms, delphi, hide

I want to hide form2 from the taskbar but i don't know how.
I do know how to hide the main form:

```
application.MainFormOnTaskBar := false;
```

But how can i hide form2 from the taskbar?

Comment: Surely Google should have provided plenty of examples... Which ones have you tried so far?

Comment: Secondary forms do not appear on the Taskbar by default. How are you making Form2 appear in the first place?

Comment: Setting MainFormOnTaskBar to false just puts the app window in the taskbar. You still get a taskbar button.  What you really want to do is create a hidden top level window and make it be the owner of your main form. An sscce would help.

Comment: I allready know how i can hide the icon from taskbar:
                                                     
ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);

Comment: Then what are you asking of us?

Answer (score 1):

In what follows, by ownership I refer to the [Windows concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) rather than the Delphi concept.

Unowned top level windows have buttons on the taskbar. By setting `MainFormOnTaskbar` to `False` you make the main form be owned by the application window. And the taskbar button is associated with the application window. You are hiding that button by hiding the application window.

If the secondary form has a button on the taskbar it presumably has no owner. That won't happen by default so one assumes you are setting `WndParent` to 0 in `CreateParams`. Or using `PopupParent` to achieve the same.

Since owned windows don't show up on the taskbar, and since it appears that you don't want the secondary form to be owned by the main form, it seems that you need to make the secondary form be owned by the application window.

Even if my guesswork above is off, the fact remains that the way to keep a window from having a taskbar button is to give it an owner.